# Compute statistical tests groupwise in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with different columns defining grouping variables, and I would like to compute a Mann-Kendall test (function `mk.test` in the package `trends`) on each of these groups.

The data is a time series (`discharge`):

```
    Date           Discharge  Year   Month      Season
    <S3: POSIXct>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <ord>      <fctr>
1   1966-01-01     13.81752   1966   January    Winter
2   1966-01-02     13.81752   1966   January    Winter
3   1966-01-03     10.98317   1966   January    Winter
4   1966-01-04     13.43362   1966   January    Winter
5   1966-01-05     13.30694   1966   January    Winter
6   1966-01-06     13.18089   1966   January    Winter
```

For now I am just computing the test on a subset of the table using:

```
mk.test(discharge$Discharge[which(discharge$Season == "Spring")])
```

But this is very laborious when it comes to *e.g.* months, therefore I would like to avoid that and use the `group_by` function from `dplyr`. I tried something like this:

```
discharge %>%
   group_by(Season) %>%
   mk.test(Discharge)
```

But get the following error message:

```
Error in mk.test(., Discharge) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

How could I compute this test in an elegant way and get for example a data frame with the grouping variable and the output of the test?

Comment: Try using the "summarize" function: ` ... %>% summarize(result=mk.test(Discharge))`

Comment: The issue with this is that the output of the test is not one value, it's structure is a list of 9.  So I get `Column Result must be length 1 (a summary value), not 9`

Comment: `summarize(result=list(mk.test(Discharge)))`

Comment: Thank you, this does work but the same issue as raised by @bcarlsen happens, namely if you want to have a look at the test, it is not necessarily obvious which group is tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mk.test` is a function that requires a numeric vector and returns a single `htest` object with 11 fields of various types. `dplr::group_by` returns a `grouped_df` object with several other classes (including `tbl` and `data.frame`). `mk.test` does not have an S3 method that supports `data.frame`, `tbl` or `grouped_df` objects.

Since `dplyr` 1.0.0 the package has included the useful functions `group_map()` and `group_modify()` that make it simpler to apply functions with complex return types across groups. These use the [tidyverse shorthand for unary anonymous functions](https://rdrr.io/cran/purrr/f/vignettes/other-langs.Rmd), where the formula operator `~` defines the function and arguments to the function are given as `.y`, .`y`, etc.

`group_map` is the simpler of the two. It behaves similar to `purrr::map` and returns a `list` object:

```
# some sample data
test <- data.frame(Season = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), Discharge = c(1,2,3,5,0,5))

test %>% group_by(Season) %>%
    group_map(~ trend::mk.test(.x$Discharge))
[[1]]

    Mann-Kendall trend test

data:  .x$Discharge
z = 1.0445, n = 3, p-value = 0.2963
alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       S     varS      tau 
3.000000 3.666667 1.000000 


[[2]]

    Mann-Kendall trend test

data:  .x$Discharge
z = 0, n = 3, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       S     varS      tau 
0.000000 2.666667 0.000000
```

However, as you can see, the names of grouping variables haven't been preserved in the output. The function return is a list of test results, stripped of context.

`group_modify()` is a little friendlier - it returns a `tbl_df` object that contains the grouping column, plus additional arbitrary columns returned by the function. However, it requires the applied function to return a `data.frame` object.

We can create a little wrapper to ensure the applied function returns an object with the right type:

```
modified_mk_test <- function(x, ...) {
  result <- mk.test(x, ...)
  
  tibble(
    p.value = result$p.value,
    statistic = result$statistic
    # and any other values you want to capture from the return
  )
}

test %>%
  group_by(Season) %>%
  group_modify(~ modified_mk_test(.x$Discharge))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Season [2]
  Season p.value statistic
   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1   0.296      1.04
2      2   1          0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!